# How to comment out blocks of code that starts/ends with some specific pattern in multiple files in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm commenting out blocks of code in multiple files named foo1.tex, ..., foo9.tex. Each block has multiple lines between one line starting with "{\bf Solution.}" and ending with "\end{ex}".

```
{\bf Solution.}
Line1
Line2
...
Line100
\end{ex}
```

Line 1~100 are lines to be commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the following macro:

`qq` to start the macro in the register `q`

Then, search for the beginning of the section that you want to comment:

```
/{\\bf Solution.}
```

Go one line down to the first to comment:

```
j
```

Go in block visual mode:

```
ctrl-v
```

Search for the end of the section:

```
/\\end{ex}
```

Go one line up to the last to comment:

```
k
```

Go in insert mode, and add the comment:

```
I%
```

Go back in normal mode and stop the macro recording:

```
<escape>q
```

You can then run the macro with:

```
@q
```

To run it on all the opened files, you can do:

```
:bufdo norm @q
```

It will comment a single block, so it'll need to be repeated if there are multiple blocks to comment.

Comment: Greatly appreciate your quick and fabulous answer!

Comment: One more question: Since I need to type "@q" many many times, is there a way to automatically do these? @padawin

Comment: In a given file, you can do: `%s/{\\bf Solution.}//n` to count the number of "Solution" blocks there are, and then call the macro this number of times: `42@q` (to call it 42 times, of course, 42 to be replaced with the actual count)

Answer (score 0):

A regex based solution could be:

```
:%s/{\\bf\_.\{-}ex}\n\zs\|^/#/g
```

This match every lines outside of the block intended to comment.

```
:%s/^/#/g
```

This add a `#` to beginning each line of the whole document

```
:%s/##//g
```

This removes double `##` characters